# uvc_camera gets a terrible image and usb_camera doesn't set framerate

Tags: ros, usb-cam, camera, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Logitech c920 webcam that I want to use with ROS. I originally installed uvc_camera, but it gets a terrible quality image from the camera. Then I tried usb_cam, which gets a fantastic quality image, but only at 10fps (which just isn't good enough).

[uvc_cam image](https://i.imgur.com/EekGz.png)

[usb_camera image](https://i.imgur.com/BFl5p.jpg)

So my question is:
How do I get a good image out of uvc OR
How do I set frame rate with usb_camera

It should be noted that guvcview gets a fantastic image using the uvc driver, though ros does not.

launch file contents:

```
FOR usb_cam:
<launch>
    <node name="camera" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
        <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
        <param name="image_width" value="1280" />
        <param name="image_height" value="720" />
        <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
        <param name="camera_frame_id" value="webcam" />
    </node>
</launch>

FOR uvc_camera:
<launch>
  <node ns="camera" pkg="uvc_camera" type="camera_node" name="uvc_camera" output="screen">
    <param name="width" type="int" value="1280" />
    <param name="height" type="int" value="720" />
    <param name="fps" type="int" value="30" />
    <param name="frame" type="string" value="webcam" />
    <param name="device" type="string" value="/dev/video1" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47209/uvc_camera-gets-a-terrible-image-and-usb_camera-doesn%27t-set-framerate/) by [Slippery John](https://answers.ros.org/users/3376/slippery-john/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-11-21**:
I have exactly the same problem with the weird color settings for the uvc_cam. To the slow frame rate of the usb_cam: do you use an usb2.0 port? $lsusb will show you...

**Comment by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) on 2016-09-12**:
I have exactly the same problem with a BW analog cam (with USB dongle on video0): vlc shows the video correctly, cheese shows the video correctly, both usb_cam and uvc_camera show purple video with different shades of green/red. No matter what pixfmt parameter I set, they always fall back to YUYV.

**Comment by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) on 2016-09-12**:
After a couple of hours spent fighting with this problem, I solved the issue. I discovered that the correct pixel format for my camera was "uyvy". For future reference, I used this launch file: https://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/working-with-ros-and-opencv-draft/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you have Logitech C920, which has hardware H264 encoding which is an awesome thing.
For usb_cam you can try it by changing the value of pixel_format to H264. Change `<param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />` to `<param name="pixel_format" value="H264" />`.
That should work and you'll get high fps with low resource usage.

---

Originally posted by [sarkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/8196/sarkar/) with karma: 36 on 2013-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-30**:
If I do as you suggested I get
[FATAL] [1383197110.463584559]: Unknown pixel format.
[ERROR] [1383197110.463895717]: VIDIOC_STREAMOFF error 9, Bad file descriptor

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-30**:
Okay uvc_cam accepts it, but the frame rate is still slow.